# Geom_Text removes geom_bar in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following R code for a stacked bar chart:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Datum, y = anzahl_tn, fill = ZUSAMMENFASSUNG))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",  color='black') +
    #geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100*percolumn),"%"), y = pos),size = 3)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","#DD1E0D","#003087","#6fa554","#7DABFF","#d6d6d6"))
ggplotly(p)
```

The result is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zTZD.png)

I would like to add labels via geom_text. However, as soon as I do so, the bars vanish:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Datum, y = anzahl_tn, fill = ZUSAMMENFASSUNG))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",  color='black') +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(100*percolumn),"%"), y = pos),size = 3)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","#DD1E0D","#003087","#6fa554","#7DABFF","#d6d6d6"))
ggplotly(p)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSmfT.png)

Data:

```
 Datum      ZUSAMMENFASSUNG    anzahl_tn percolumn      pos
   <date>     <fct>                  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2020-10-01 A                       9548     0.258 2745326 
 2 2020-10-01 B                       8213     0.222 2040286.
 3 2020-10-01 C                       5887     0.159 1404390.
 4 2020-10-01 D                       4192     0.113  932105 
 5 2020-10-01 E                       5043     0.136  525418.
 6 2020-10-01 F                       4106     0.111  194945 
 7 2020-11-01 A                       10603     0.267 3082634.
 8 2020-11-01 B                       9235     0.233 2099054.
 9 2020-11-01 C                       6108     0.154 1452656 
10 2020-11-01 D                       4380     0.110 1009419
```

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Could we have an exemple of your dataset so that we can reproduce ? thanks

Comment: You are using y = pos for geom_text and y = anzahl_fn for geom_bar. They are likely of quite different order.